# What is the way to show the progress of calculations?

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to monitor my program which is running on the web server.
Can I draw the progress bar or simply show the percentage which is returned by my code?
The php script is spawning the external code with parameters.

```
 $Status="rendering...";
 $cmd = "cd $rpath && $envopts /home/arm2arm/bin/sph2grid";
 $shellcmd=$cmd.$params.'| tee  sph2grid.log ';
 echo '<strong>'.$shellcmd.'</strong>';
 $tmp=shell_exec($shellcmd);
```

then after all I am showing the log file:

```
 <?php
 function ViewLog() {
 $string = file_get_contents('../../PHP-Login/tmp/sph2grid.log');
 $string = str_replace("\n", '<br>', $string);
 echo $string;
 }    
 ?>
```

Can I bind the output of my application to some `"<div>"`?

Thanks in advance.

Arman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can use javascript to setup a timer interval that spawns ajax processes to poll a php page where the percentage is being output. you can then grab the response of that page and append it to a div:

```
setInterval (pollPage, 1000);
function pollPage()
{
   $.get("percentageComplete.php",output);
}

function output(data)
{
    $("#yourDiv").empty().append(data);

}
```

in percentageComplete.php you need to get the percentage completed of the calculations

Comment: unfortunately the hardest part here is what you put in the percentageComplete.php file

Comment: well, that depends on what is being logged. The php file can parse the log and get that info.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. are there way to stop the timer? Should I put the timer to infinity to stop it?

Comment: First store the reference to yout timeout on a variable

var t=setInterval (pollPage, 1000);

to stop it:

clearTimeout(t);